# Angular how to download file from S3 Amazon using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from my amazon S3 bucket by using angular ng-click. But instead of file it returns me with blank file on download.

## HTML

```
<div class="details-field"> RC Book 
  <font class="digit" >({{rcCount}})</font> : <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-button" ng-click=download() ></i>
</div>
```

## Angular script

```
var awsUrl = https://s3.amazonaws.com/thdoc/ ;
$scope.download = function() {
  $http.get(awsUrl, {
    responseType: "arraybuffer"
  })
  .success(function(data) {
     var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
     var blob = new Blob([data]);
     anchor.attr({
       href: window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
       target: '_blank',
       download: 'RCBook_406_20170328_222831_644.jpg'
     })[0].click();
  })
}
```

Any help will be great on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: why cant you directly bind the url to href

Comment: @Sajeetharan can you please replica that one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this,

```
<a href="{{ url }}" target="_blank" >Trusted URL</a><br><br>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cuxorawiju/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: But i have different buttons for different files how could i check to download that file using this ?

Comment: you need to use ng-repeat

Comment: how ? sorry but i am getting confused.

Comment: you need to create a list of objects with name and url, then use ng-repeat to generate buttons with href set from the object

Comment: could you please help me to do so. any code please.

Comment: it is simple if you are aware of ng-repeat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164526/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-tanmoy-sarkar).

Comment: you fixed it!? great dude!

Comment: yaa used your code with some simple logic. Thanks for youe help.